# Changed root MySQL password to an empy string now I can't access database

Tags: mysql

I wanted to get rid of the password requirement for my MySQL and (stupidly) thought I could just change it to an empty string. I ran the command:

```
mysqladmin -u -p[mypassword] password ''
```

I received a warning message that "single quotes were not trimmed from the command line client as you would expect".
I now get access denied for all password attempts including my old password, explicitly putting in '', leaving it blank.

I have run the command `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`as I have seen suggested in other questions but this has no effect, I still get access denied after running this command.

I have also tried following the guidance here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows and I get the folowing output at which point the command does nothing.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --console --init-file=C:\\Users\Tobyb\Documents\mysql-init.txt
2018-08-20T12:09:50.433487Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 14300
2018-08-20T12:09:52.193012Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-08-20T12:09:52.245255Z 6 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] 1105  Bootstrap file error, return code (0). Nearest query: ''
2018-08-20T12:09:52.248615Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.12'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Is there any other way for me to regain acces to my database or change the password?

Thanks

**Edit:** Due to time constraints I've gone for the nuclear option and, thankfully having backup sql files, done a complete reinstall of MySQL Server. For anyone who may come across this problem and it still hasn't been solved, if you do a clean install be sure to delete **all** remaining MySQL Server files, otherwise the the problem will persist after the reinstall. Preferably use an uninstaller such as revo.

Comment: Have you tried `mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password 'newpassword'` just taking a look at this source here. Seems like you may have read through it though. https://serverfault.com/questions/103412/how-to-change-my-mysql-root-password-back-to-empty

Comment: Did you try omitting user and password? Perhaps you enabled noauth?

Comment: @Isaac Yeah that was the page I originally followed to try and change my password to an empty string which has now led to me having no access

Comment: Unsure as to why there isn't a failsafe to stop you creating a password, that will no longer let you login to your database.

Comment: My thoughts exactly! I'm fairly new to SQL/MySQL and wasn't expecting it to be so easy to lock myself out like that.

Comment: Remember MySQL, like many databases, does not ask "Are you sure?" even when doing something spectacularly stupid like `DROP DATABASE critical_production_no_backups_ever;`. It just does what you ask, without question. This is why it's always important to read the documentation closely before running anything you're not absolutely certain about. It's also important to have backups and verify that you can restore from them so you can revert any blunders you make. Anyone with significant database experience has, of course, made some huge mistakes in the past.

Answer (score 0):

try  mysqladmin -u   ,'' is not empty password